# FileNotFoundException while adding file in cache - Hadoop - Mapreduce

Tags: java, file, memory, hadoop, mapreduce

Note : I have gone through posts with similar problems here already and tried different approaches suggested there, but still unable to fix the problem.

I want to add a file which is in HDFS to cache memory of the mappers, so I added it in the driver program as given below :

```
//Driver program
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

Job job = Job.getInstance(new Configuration(), "QuestionOne"); 
Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();

// I am passing my file path(which is in HDFS) as an argument. Eg : /input/users.dat
job.addCacheFile(new URI(args[1])); 

job.setJarByClass(QuestionOne.class); 
job.setMapperClass(Map.class); 
job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

...
System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1); 
}
```

Followed by map class to retrieve the file & use it as :

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{


protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    ...

    URI[] files = context.getCacheFiles();

    for(URI p : files) {
        System.out.println(p.getPath().toString()); // prints "/input/users.dat"

        // Exception (FileNotFoundException) at this line
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(p.getPath().toString())));

        // Use br

        br.close();     
    }
}

protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {           
        ...
        ...
}

protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ...
        ...
}
}
```

But I get FileNotFoundException when I run the program as given below :

```
14/10/25 03:00:29 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local30078493_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /input/users.dat (No such file or directory)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /hw1_input/users.dat (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
    at QuestionOne$Map.setup(QuestionOne.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
14/10/25 03:00:30 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local30078493_0001 running in uber mode : false
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use distributed file system, not the local one:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(context.getConfiguration());
for (URI p : files) {
    Path path = new Path(p.toString());
    FSDataInputStream fsin = fs.open(path);
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fsin);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    //Use br

    br.close();
    in.close();
    fsin.close();           
}
```